# _io.StringIO object has no attribute 'encode'

Tags: object, attributes, encode

im trying to convert pdf file to rtf format and i got this error _io.StringIO object has no attribute 'encode' so if any one with an idea how to fix it please share it with me.

i don't know from where this error is coming so, help me with this.

Comment: Where is your code?

Comment: Also please include the language tag.